# Ultraproduct of cyclic groups

Tags: model-theory

I would like to know whether my proofs are correct or not.

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the ultraproduct of cyclic groups $\mathcal{M}_i = \mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}$ in the $L_{agrp}$ language. I would like to prove that:

1. $\mathcal{M}$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$:
   Assume that it doesn't, than every element $b$ of $\mathcal{M}$ has a finite order $n$. As $b$ is expressible as $1+\ldots + 1 = b$ formalize its finite order as a first-order sentence $\varphi(b)=1+\ldots+1 = 0$. Sentence $\varphi(b)$ holds in groups of sufficiently big order and thus, according to Los theorem, in $\mathcal{M}$.
2. $\mathcal{M}$ may or may not contain an element $a$ of order 2:
   Here I take principal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ generated by $2$. This implies that $\mathcal{M}\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and thus has an element of order 2.
   For counterexample take principal ultrafilter generated by $3$, the same argument applies.

Comment: If you're allowing principal ultrafilters, then your argument for (1) breaks down. If you're not - and I suspect this is the case - then your argument for (2) breaks down. (Either way, you shouldn't say "the" ultraproduct since what you get depends on what ultrafilter is used.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a *lot* of issues here, packed densely into a short post, so let's take this line-by-line.

> Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the ultraproduct of cyclic groups $\mathcal{M}_i = \mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}$ in the $L_{agrp}$ language.

As Noah points out in the comments, you should first fix an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$. Then you can defined $\mathcal{N}$ to be the ultraproduct *by the ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$*: $\mathcal{M} = \prod_{\mathcal{U}} \mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}$.

> I would like to prove that ... $\mathcal{M}$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

When $\mathcal{U}$ is a principal ultrafilter (generated by $n$, say), this is false, since $\mathcal{M}\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ does not contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. So let's agree to assume $\mathcal{U}$ is non-principal.

> Assume that it doesn't, than every element $b$ of $\mathcal{M}$ has a finite order $n$.

Yes, in this case every element has finite order, but we should be careful to observe that the order $n$ depends on the element $b$ (there may be elements of arbitrarily large order).

> As $b$ is expressible as $1+\ldots + 1 = b$ ...

Why should that be true? The ultraproduct is definitely not a cyclic group. Also, what element of $\mathcal{M}$ are you denoting by $1$? The equivalence class of the sequence $(\overline{1},\overline{1},\overline{1},\dots)$? The element $[(\overline{0},\overline{0},\overline{1},\overline{2},\overline{3},\dots)]_{\mathcal{U}}$ is an example of an element which is not a finite sum $1+\dots+1$.

> ... formalize its finite order as a first-order sentence $\varphi(b)=1+\ldots+1 = 0$.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If $b$ is $\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{k\text{ times}}$, and $b$ has order $n$, is the formula you're considering $\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{nk\text{ times}} = 0$? Note that this is not a sentence in the language of abelian groups, since $1$ is not a constant symbol in this language.

> Sentence $\varphi(b)$ holds in groups of sufficiently big order and thus, according to Los theorem, in $\mathcal{M}$.

So what's the contradiction? We already know $b$ has finite order in $\mathcal{M}$, and you're saying that the formula asserting its finite order holds in $\mathcal{M}$...

Maybe you meant to say that $\lnot \varphi(b)$ holds in groups of sufficiently large order, and thus $\lnot\varphi(b)$ holds in $\mathcal{M}$, contradiction?

This argument can be cleaned up and corrected by forgetting about the arbitrary element $b$ entirely. Instead, define $1$ to be the element $[(\overline{1},\overline{1},\overline{1},\dots)]_{\mathcal{U}}\in \mathcal{M}$. I claim that $1$ has infinite order in $\mathcal{M}$, and hence generates a cyclic subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. For any natural number $n\geq 1$, let $\varphi_n(x)$ be the formula $\underbrace{x+\dots+x}_{n\text{ times}}$. Then $$\{i\in \mathbb{N}\mid \mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}\models\varphi_n(\overline{1})\} = \{i\in \mathbb{N}\mid i|n\}\notin \mathcal{U},$$ since the set is finite and $\mathcal{U}$  is non-principal. By Łoś's theorem, $\mathcal{M}\models \lnot \varphi_n(1)$. So $1$ does not have finite order in $\mathcal{M}$.

> I would like to prove that ... $\mathcal{M}$ may or may not contain an element $a$ of order 2:
> Here I take principal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ generated by $2$. This implies that $\mathcal{M}\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and thus has an element of order 2.  For counterexample take principal ultrafilter generated by $3$, the same argument applies.

You can certainly do this, but we agreed to assume $\mathcal{U}$ is non-principal above, since part 1 is false for principal ultrafilters.

Note that by Łoś's theorem, $\mathcal{M}$ has an element of order $2$ if and only if $$\{i\in \mathbb{N}\mid \mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}\models \exists x\, (x+x=0)\}\in \mathcal{U}$$ if and only if the set $E$ of even numbers is in $\mathcal{U}$ (since $\mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}\models \exists x\, (x+x=0)$ if and only if $i$ is even).

To find an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ such that $\prod_{\mathcal{U}} \mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}$ has an element of order $2$, extend the filter $F_E$ generated by the set of even numbers together with all cofinite sets to an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$.

To find an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ such that $\prod_{\mathcal{U}} \mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z}$ does not have an element of order $2$, extend the filter $F_O$ generated by the set of odd numbers together with all cofinite sets to an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I wasn't sure if such an ultrafilter (containing odd numbers) exists, so I defined it as follows: $J_i := \{0\ldots 2i\}$ and $\mathcal{A}:= \{ \mathbb{N}\setminus J_0, \mathbb{N}\setminus J_1, \mathbb{N}\setminus J_2, \ldots \}$. Because intersection over finitely-many sets in $\mathcal{A}$ is non-empty, there exists an ultrafilter which contains $\mathcal{A}$ (and thus the odd numbers). Is that correct?

Comment: @averagemathenjoyer The sets in $\mathcal{A}$ are cofinite, so they are in *every* non-principal ultrafilter. Let $E = \{2n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $O = \{2n+1\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. The set $\mathcal{A}\cup \{E\}$ has the finite intersection property, so it extends to an ultrafilter (which contains $E$ and hence does not contain $O$). $\mathcal{A}$ also extends to a principal ultrafilter, for example the one generated by $1$. To get a non-principal ultrafilter containing $O$, you need the construction I suggested in the last sentence of my answer.